# T-SQL Efficiently assign Tables to group according to Table seats and group Persons

Tags: sql-server, combinations, sql-server-2019

I've always used programming languages to work with combinations, but since latest project has more than 40 tables,
I was wondering if better result can be achieved via TSQL, although there is always the DB bottleneck to consider:

I understand that this kind of question is probably OT but..

Anyway, problem is quite simple:

I have 2 `tables`: `@Tables` that contains the name of the table and its seats and `@Families` containing the name of the family and the number of the persons

I need to sit all persons trying to avoid to leave unused seats in each table (and move as less as possible the tables)

Rules are: I can join 2 or more tables but I lose 1 seat for each added table (if it is a 3 seat table, else I lose 2 seats) except the case of 3+3 = 6 => 6

```
ie: T1+T2 = 3+3 = 6 => 6, T2+T3= 6+3 = 9 => 8, T1+T2+T3 = 6+3+3 = 12 =>10, T3+T4+T5 = 6+5+3 = 14 =>11
```

At the end I will have that:

`John` family will use `T2` and `T3`,
`Jo` will use `T4` and `T5`,
`Jill` will use `T1` and `T6`,
`Jack` will use `T7`,
while `T8`, `T9` and `T10` will remain unused

To avoid to calculate all possible combinations we can set some limitations:
Family's persons is `<=10` and that tables count is `<=4` (since `4xT(3) = 12 => 10`)

here the queries to simulate the data and the expected result

```
    insert into @Tables ([name],seats, family) Values ('T1', 3, null),('T2',3, null),('T3',6, null),('T4',5, null),('T5',3, null),('T6',3, null),('T7',5, null),('T8',3, null),('T9',3, null),('T10',3, null)
    insert into @Families ([name],persons,[tables]) Values ('John', 8, null),('Jack',4, null),('Jill',6, null),('Jo',7, null)
    
    select * from @Tables
    select * from @Families
    
    delete from @Tables
    delete from @Families

    --therefore at the end of the query the two tables will look like:
    insert into @Tables ([name],seats, family) Values ('T1', 3, 'Jill'),('T2',3, 'John'),('T3',6, 'John'),('T4',5, 'Jo'),('T5',3, 'Jo'),('T6',3, 'Jill'),('T7',6, 'Jack'),('T8',3, null),('T9',3, null),('T10',3, null)
    insert into @Families ([name],persons,[tables]) Values ('John', 8,'["T2","T3"]'),('Jack',4,'["T7"]'),('Jill',6,'["T1","T6]'),('Jo',7,'["T4","T5"]')

    select * from @Tables
    select * from @Families
    select * from @Tables where family is null
```

Can somebody suggest the path to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: This, honestly, doesn't sound like a task for SQL Server; a programmatical solution will likely be better.

Comment: See Bin Packing in SQL: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/bin-packing-problems-the-sql/#:~:text=Bin%20Packing%20Problems%3A%20The%20SQL%20The%20%27bin%20packing%27,The%20bin%20packing%20problem%20is%20an%20NP-complete%20problem.

Comment: well, this is easily solveable since you don't specify penalty for splitting families

Comment: @siggemannen: actually.. family cannot be splitted but on the contrary need to join tables

Comment: Yes, but did you actually mention it in your description

Comment: @siggemannen: sorry, I did not consider that since rule is to join tables

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft:thanks a lot: that seems a good example to start working on